# Clarification on the "object pool" pattern?

Tags: c++, objectpool, boost-pool

I was under the impression that an `object pool` is a design pattern used for managing a group of pre-allocated objects to which a client can request and be returned one of these objects.  However, it seems that `boost.pool`'s `object_pool` class has more to do with lower-level memory management than object management.  Why did they go with this name, as opposed to something like `memory_pool`?  Am I under the wrong impression that boost's object pool is really a memory pooling scheme?  Or are they essentially the same thing?  Also, why hasn't there been a standard implementation of a more high-level object pool pattern?

Comment: Are you thinking of something like a [slab allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation).  That is a pattern that keeps some common object properties initialized so that the object is partially constructed in the pool?  I think that it would be hard to model *partially* constructed object in C++.  How would they be *completed*? An interesting question though.

Comment: Are you confusing allocation with construction?

Comment: I have provided an answer which I believe addresses my confusion, although feel free to comment if it sounds like my interpretation of `boost.pool` implementation is wrong.

Comment: Hi, thx for the question. I also have the same question. i need an "Object Pool" so that i can reuse objects. does boost provide anything in this direction? or is there any advantage to using `boost::pool` over a simple hand made "Object pool" which simply reuses objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading more thoroughly into the `boost.pool` documentation, I think I understand my confusion.  I'm used to thinking of an object pool implemented as a class which allocates and manages a set of *direct* objects.  Consider,

```
template<class T>
class object_pool {
private:
  std::list<T*> m_reserved; // holds onto any objects that have been allocated
public
  T *acquire() { /* grabs from reserved list */ }
};
```

However, it seems `boost.pool` implements a different concept of object pooling, one used for a completely different purpose than the one as suggested above.  `boost.pool` allocates and manages the *underlying memory* of the desired object(s), presumably so that it can increase heap performance by means of what it describes as [Simple Segregated Storage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/pooling.html#boost_pool.pool.pooling.simple).  It in fact does **not** follow [this concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) of the object pool pattern.  An explanation on the distinction between the two patterns can be found in the answer to my [subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847359/how-does-boost-pool-achieve-re-use-of-allocated-memory).

Comment: [This concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) is much like a [slab allocator/look-aside cache](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-8-sect-2).